# Retrieve POST data with HTTP server hosted on Android

Tags: android, http, post, serversocket

I found an example of [how to implement a HTTP server hosted on Android](http://android-er.blogspot.fr/2014/08/implement-simple-http-server-running-on.html?m=1).
It works fine with HTTP GET method.

Here's the code that reads the `Socket`'s `InputStream` and writes to its `OutputStream` :

```
private class HttpResponseThread extends Thread {

    Socket socket;
    String h1;

    HttpResponseThread(Socket socket, String msg) {
        this.socket = socket;
        h1 = msg;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader br;
        PrintWriter pw;
        String request;

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            request = br.readLine();

            pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            String response =
                    "<html><head></head>" +
                            "<body>" +
                            "<h1>" + h1 + "</h1>" +
                            "</body></html>";

            pw.print("HTTP/1.0 200" + "\r\n");
            pw.print("Content type: text/html" + "\r\n");
            pw.print("Content length: " + response.length() + "\r\n");
            pw.print("\r\n");
            pw.print(response + "\r\n");
            pw.flush();

            msgLog += String.format("Request of %s from %s\n", request, socket.getInetAddress().toString());

            socket.close();

            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    infoMsg.setText(msgLog);
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For instance, with the url `<android_device_ip>:<server_port>?foo=bar`, the output is :

> Request of /?foo=bar from "client_ip"

Here I can easily retrieve the GET data (`foo=bar`). But instead of using HTTP GET method, I'd like to use HTTP POST method...

But I don't see how to do it.

PS : for more information about the rest of the code, see [here](http://android-er.blogspot.fr/2014/08/implement-simple-http-server-running-on.html?m=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP POST data is stored in the HTTP payload section of a message. So, in order to retrieve them you would need to first parse the payload part. To do this, simplest way is reading from the input stream until you reach `"\r\n\r\n"`. After facing this pattern, the rest is called payload. So, you will have got two parts:

- Before `"\r\n\r\n"`: This part is HTTP headers separated by `"\r\n"`.
- After `"\r\n\r\n"`: This part is HTTP POST data in the form of:

  ```
  key1=value1&key2=value2&...
  ```

Comment: and where does the payload section of a message is stored? In socket.getInputStream()?

Comment: @Drarig29 Yes, read all input stream and split it by `"\r\n\r\n"`.

Comment: "split" is probably not the right word to use. You need to read from `InputStream` until `"\r\n\r\n"` is encountered to end the request headers. Then you have to parse the headers to know 1) if a body is sent, 2) how it is encoded, and 3) how it is terminated. Only then can you read the body data from the `InputStream` (refer to [RFC 2616 section 4.4 Message Length](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) for more details) and then parse the body based on the type specified by the `Content-Type` request header (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, etc).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, you're absolutely right. We should read from input stream until we reach `"\r\n\r\n" `.